# Chi Squared Kernel and Faster implementation

Tags: machine-learning, chi-squared-test, svm, kernel-trick, large-data

[This](http://www.vlfeat.org/matlab/vl_alldist2.html) is a good implementation of $\chi^2$ Kernel.

But this implementation is very slow when input data is huge. This implementation doesn't accept the sparse data input (my data is very sparse).

1. Can we convert this implementation compatible to sparse inputs?
2. Is there any other fast implementation of Chi-squared kernel?

Comment: If you are looking to learn SVMs with Chi-Square kernel (or intersection kernels), there are some works where the kernels are approximative additive while being much faster and also sacrificing almost no accuracy. See the works by Subhransu Maji, for exampe http://acberg.com/papers/mbm2012pami.pdf

Comment: And this work on efficient intersection kernel in SVM https://people.cs.umass.edu/~smaji/papers/iksvm-cvpr08.pdf. The intersection kernel as well as chi-square kernels are good choice when working with histogram type data.

Answer (score 2):

First of all how much slow and how much are big your input?

I'm starting to say that I never use VLFeat library, but maybe the following solution, that I used in one of my matlab' scripts, can be useful.

```
function kernel=chiSquared(mat1,mat2)

kernel = zeros(size(mat1,1),size(mat2,1));

for i=1:size(mat2,1)
    d = bsxfun(@minus, mat1, mat2(i,:));
    s = bsxfun(@plus, mat1, mat2(i,:));
    kernel(:,i) = sum(d.^2 ./ (s/2+eps), 2);
end
kernel = 1 - kernel;
```

This function take me something like 2.54 seconds with 800x750 input matrix and you can use also sparse matrix inside.

But be aware this is the conditionally positive definite version of chi square kernel, that is:

$$
\ k(x,y) = 1-\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{2(x_{i}-y_{i})^2}{(x_{i}+y_{i})}\
$$

Now in my case 2.5 second it was acceptable, but if you want more speed, probably you need to write it directly in C.
I hope the solution I adopted can help you.